# Meaning of "to appeal to some law"

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

This [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning) says that:

> David Hume's problem of induction demonstrates that one must appeal to the principle of the uniformity of nature if they seek to justify their implicit assumption that laws which held true in the past will also hold true in the future.

For which I'm confused about how to interpret the meaning of *appeal* in this sentence. Most of the dictionaries I consulted suggest that the phrase *appeal to* can only be followed by one or more people or organizations but here it is followed by *to some law*. So how should I interpret that sentence?

Comment: There is no reason for not using *appeal to* when addressing one thing. Here, one appeals to logic. I'd question "**one** must appeal to ... to justify **their** implicit assumption."

Comment: 'Appeal' to there means 'call upon' or 'invoke' or even simply 'use.'

Comment: @YosefBaskin "I'd question ..." Why?  That was correct usage before current woke insertions and avoids the ugly his/her (when unknown gender) construct.  Going forwards, 'they/their' is a recognised single person pronoun (regardless of how much one looks at it and instinctively thinks "nahhh") which makes it even more not incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appeal) gives perhaps the most relevant definition of those available online without paywalls:

> **appeal** ...
>
> [4] [appeal to]: to call upon another for corroboration, vindication,
> or decision

though the sense is usually used with the appeal being made to a (sentient!) advocate. Indeed, there is a metaphorical dimension.

[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/appeal) also comes close

> **appeal** [verb] [intransitive] ...
>
> [2] To have recourse, as for corroboration; resort [; invoke, see [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/invoke)]:
>
> - [with transitivising particle/preposition] *I appeal to your sense of justice*.

Here, the sense is surely also informed by the legal usage [[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=appeal+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=appeal+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.5033j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]:

> **appeal** [verb; transitive or intransitive]: apply to a higher court for a reversal of the decision of a lower court.

There is at least a strong hint that different laws / guiding principles are in conflict here, and *the principle of the uniformity of nature* needs to be ranked as binding if one is to justify the assumption that *laws which held true in the past will also hold true in the future*. There's more than a hint of tautology: *the principle of the uniformity of nature* essentially ***is*** the assumption that *laws which held true in the past will also hold true in the future*.

Answer (score 6):

**appeal to [something]** in the context of debate or philosophical argument can be paraphrased as "to invoke something as a foundation, support, or justification for a position taken".

> The argument that a person must be acquitted of a crime when the evidence used to convict them had been acquired via an illegal wire-tap appeals to the need to protect the right to privacy when using telecommunication systems.

Answer (score 5):

Oxford Languages gives:

> try to persuade someone to do something by calling on (a particular principle or quality).
> "I appealed to his sense of justice"

The paragraph is saying that you have to 'call on' the Principle of the Uniformity of Nature (which you can look up) to 'persuade' people to believe that laws which held true in the past will hold true in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> *... demonstrates that one must **appeal to**...*

*Appeal (to)* is a speech term, in particular a term used in describing debate.  This is a metaphor, since no speech is going on. The writer (no one speaks naturally like this) is anticipating an objection and claiming that there is a further principle involved, and they are appealing to that principle, as one would to a deity, to rescue them.

From what they're being rescued is not clear. "The Principle of the Uniformity of Nature" is simply the null hypothesis for human perception and belief, what we call "presupposition" nowadays -- stuff you hafta take for granted to understand what others say and do. But this is an imaginary debate, so it has an imaginary rescue.